NVidia GPU Fan not recognized
I'm unable to set the speed of my NVidia GPU fan, in fact, it's not spinning at all.
Acer Nitro AN515-58 with NVidia 3070 Ti, Ubuntu 24.04, NVidia Driver 535 (Tried 550 as well, it's even more buggy, not working with my secondary external display, etc)
When running the command nvidia-settings -a GPUFanControlState=1 -a GPUTargetFanSpeed=60
i get the error:
Attribute 'GPUFanControlState' (jerryyy:1[gpu:0]) assigned value 1.


ERROR: Error resolving target specification '' (No targets match target
       specification), specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=60'.

So basically I think it doesn't recognize the GPU fan at all. It does not even work with third party tools, like nbfc. That only turns on the cpu fan. Neither works with GreenWithEnvy and it's not appearing in NVidia X Settings, even if coolbits is on 4.
What could I do?

Opened laptop, removed battery, removed gpu fan, reinstalled battery and fan voila, it works.
